# How does getStaticProps() render fetched data in the initial HTML file?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

According to the Next.js official site, pre-rendered pages first display the pre-rendered HTML and then hydrate it by initializing the React components and making it interactive (adding the event listeners). If this is the case, how is it that the `props` passed to the component via `getStaticProps()` (see generic example below) manipulate the initial HTML render? Isn't the React code just running server-side to inject the desired data into the pre-rendered HTML, then running again later to hydrate it?

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Get external data from the file system, API, DB, etc.
  const data = ...

  // The value of the `props` key will be
  //  passed to the `Home` component
  return {
    props: ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps()` works even when there is no "server-side", i.e. when you've `next export`ed your site to just static files. Hence it's not "React code just running server-side".

If you look at a `next export`ed page, you'll see it's something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="/_next/client-side-script-stuff-here.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="__next" data-reactroot="">
    <h1>Bare rendered HTML here, no scripts...</h1>
  </div>
  <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"somePageProp":...}}, "__N_SSG":true},"page":"/","query":{},"buildId":"..."}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's the `client-side-script-stuff-here.js` in conjunction with the injected `__NEXT_DATA__` that has React and Next's machinery hydrate the page.